# Configure guest in virt-manager to use host's VPN?

Tags: virt-manager

One thread mentions to use a bridged or macvtap connection, but every device I put results in an 'operation unsupported' error or the VM doesn't connect to any network when I start it (though when I connect a macvtap to my host's regular NIC, the VM's network works but not through the VPN). Another said the easiest solution is to simply install the VPN client on the VM, but isn't there a simple way to just tell it to use the host's VPN?

Update:

By 'put' I mean I enter into the Device text box. E.g. if my host's (main) NIC device is enp2s0, I input that. Inputting wg-mullvad (one of the devices listed after running $ ip a) results in 'operation unsupported', and I'm not sure if that's the device I'm even supposed to input. After attempting the NAT default, I tried every combination of bridged and macvtap with the devices listed by $ ip a, and none gave me the desired result of the VM being given the same public IP as my host's VPN, or at least any IP assigned by the VPN.

Now that I tried to test it again, I'm stuck on No active connection to install on when I attempt to create a new VM (I deleted the previous one to start from a clean slate). I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932200/kvm-virt-manager-error-no-active-connection-to-installed-on) thread before (when I had the same No active connection issue), and installing the mentioned packages (except for libvirt-bin which apt couldn't find; my host is Debian Testing) solved the problem, so now I'm not sure.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Which device do you put? What does "put" mean? Which action results in "operation unsupported"? Please describe your network setup, and how you attempt to connect the VM to the host network and to the VPN.

Comment: Edited. Also, the initial configuration was with the NAT default which I thought would work, but the VM had no network access. After some time, I figured it might be because of my host's VPN connection and when I disconnected it, the VM could connect. I then spent the next hours trying to figure out a simple way to have the VM use my host's VPN connection.

Comment: Since I don't know what wg-mullvad is, I can't tell you why it can't be used. I also I can't say how a NAT'd VM can be made to use the host's VPN, but if you use a bridge, you could plug the VPN's TAP or TUN interface into the same bridge as the VM. How that impacts the VPN on the host, I am not sure.

Comment: Sounds like the common 'problem' of multiple ways to do things and not being sure which is the best/simplest, but sure, I can try that. Haven't seen any instructions for TAP/TUN but I'll look it up.

Comment: Maybe @slybloty has an answer? He replied on a similar thread but his answer didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still having this issue with Mullvad VPN, maybe typing "mullvad lan set allow" in your terminal will help.